# Origin of holes at 800 m depth in the Mediterranean

Tags: marine-biology, invertebrates

From 8 to 12 small 2-3 cm holes in the bottom mud are forming rounds with a diameter of 20-40 cm. No tentacles or other body parts have been observed. Mediterranean sea, 600-1000 m.
What are they?
[image]

Comment: Where's the picture from? What makes you think you're looking at biology?

Comment: -The picture is from subsea remote operated vehicle. It doesn't look like an occasional structure in mud. There are many of them with the same pattern.

Comment: Is it your picture, or someone else's?

Comment: I've made it, yes

Comment: I take it the 20-40 cm is the diameter between the green lines and the 2-3 cm holes are each of the 9 shapes?, or is it that the 9 shapes are 20-40 cm across each? I'd suspect a moving mollusc or something similar, or perhaps a fish hunting for sub-surface feed.

Comment: 50 cm between the lines

Comment: Can you comment on when these formed (that is, did you observe this ground without the holes last year, but this year they appear? Or is this the first time you see them and they could have formed many years ago?) Can you comment on how solid or soft this ground is (does it leave footprints like sand, or is it harder like dirt?) Have you seen several of these rings, or just this one?

Comment: 1)Have no idea wether it's appeared this year, but I think it should be something usual. Something, that should be known by zoologists. That's the first time I see such structures. 2) Ground is very soft. It's a mud or dust. It's lifting up with ROV propellers. 3) There are many of rings. Sometimes there are two of them (like 8) or even three. –